# Help Extracting a CramFS filesystem from .img binary

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, firmware-analysis

I'm trying to extract a CramFS filesystem from a firmware binary for the FVS318Gv2. It downloads as a .zip file that can be decompressed to reveal a firmware .img file and a readme.htm. Running `binwalk -I firmware.img` provides

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
43            0x2B            Intel x86 or x64 microcode, sig 0x00000020, pf_mask 0x80a30145, 00B0-00-00, rev 0x-78ee0000, size 3
64            0x40            CramFS filesystem, big endian, size 27492352, version 2, sorted_dirs, CRC 0x0C576106, edition 0, 14673 blocks, 1925 files
```

I've used DD to isolate the cramfs system mentioned on there with `dd bs=1 skip=64 count=27492352 if=firmware.img of=firmware.cramfs status=progress` and that returns a file where the output of `binwalk -I firmware.cramfs` returns

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             CramFS filesystem, big endian, size 27492352, version 2, sorted_dirs, CRC 0x0C576106, edition 0, 14673 blocks, 1925 files
```

Afterwards, I've tried running fsck.cramfs to decompress the file and the only thing returned is `fsck.cramfs: unsupported filesystem features` which I can only assume is because the shifted root filesystem flag is set in the superblock. At this point I do not know what that means or how to resolve it. I've tried swapping the endianess of it but the shifted root fs error still occurs with cramfsswap. Can anybody help?